# JQuery File Upload event from Edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to add JQuery File Upload to Product model for adding images. 
My edit.html.erb

```
...
<%= file_field_tag "fileupload", 
multiple: "", 
"data-url" => 
  "#{add_image_admin_products_path(product_id: @product.id)}" %>
```

It generates this input:

```
<input data-url="/admin/products/add_image?product_id=2" id="fileupload" multiple="multiple" name="fileupload" type="file">
```

But when adding file action is firing I get the Error:

```
 Error 404
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::ProductsController#update.
```

**EDITED**

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :products do
      collection do
        post 'add_image'
        post 'destroy_image'
      end
    end
  end
```

and add_image action in products_controller:

```
def add_image
    render :json => {:Result => "Ok"}
end
```

Comment: routes file? Result of rake routes = ? Is there an add_image action in  Admin::ProductsController?

Comment: I've edited post recently.

Comment: The first step to debug this is to `right-click` & `view-source` on your rendered `edit` HTML. This will allow you to see the path being rendered in your form (and consequently where `jquery file upload` is sending your file)

Comment: I would surmise that your `jquery-file-upload` will be using the form's `action` argument to determine the path; hence taking the upload to the `update` action, rather than `add_image`!

Comment: In debugger I see that '/admin/products/add_image?product_id=2' is firing.